# Resize Google Map Marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add customized google map pin on my google map API. My image is big 135px(w) x 185px (h), i want to make it smaller , eg in 26px(w) x 35px(h) to looks fit in googlemap. Is that anyway can make the pin looks smaller besides resize the image using tools (ps/ai)? 
How to add scaledSize?

```
var map = { 
    control: {},
    center: {
        latitude: xxx,
        longitude: yyy

    },
    zoom: 17,
    options: {
        mapTypeControl: mapTypeControl,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: 1, // GoogleMapApi.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            position: 1, // GoogleMapApi.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: zoomControl,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: 0, // google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
            position: 5, // google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        scrollwheel: true,
        panControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        draggable: true,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 15,
    },
    trigger: false,
    bounds: {},
    dragging: false,
    events: { 
        dragend: function() {

        },
        click: function(map, eventName, args) {

        },
        idle: function() {

        }
    },
    rebuildWindows: false,
    templateUrl: 'templates/infowindow.html'
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: The map {} object above has nothing to do at all with the "customized google map pin" mentioned in the question.

Comment: @davidkonrad i want to resize the marker.

Comment: The above code shows no marker.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

Answer (score -1):

If the image you want to use as a marker is too big, the first (but obvious) advice should be to change the size of your image, to fit your needs.

However, you can do it programatically :

```
var customPin = new google.maps.MarkerImage("../path-of-you-pin/myPin.png"),
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
// or use the size you want, this are the default sizes
```

And use it like this :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   // ...
   icon: customPin,
   // ...
});
```